# Disable caching on specific url pattern - htaccess

Tags: php, apache, caching

My website has a dashboard for which I want to disable caching, as pages are generated dynamically. All dashboard pages have following pattern:

```
https://mywebsite.com/app
https://mywebsite.com/app/users
...
```

Other than the above pattern, I want to cache everything. The following `.htaccess` caches everything, my dashboard pages don't update:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304, public"
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270902/set-apache-headers-conditionally

Comment: @Oldskool I am using shared hosting