# Can I only set Access-Control-Allow-xxx header with origin url condition on Apache CORS

Tags: apache, cors

I'm new in Apache server configuration, now I try to enable CORS.

With follow setting in httpd.conf, CORS can work properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"
</VirtualHost>
```

But current server always set Access-Control-Allow-xxx header to all coming request (Both Pre-flight OPTIONS request and actual request).

I only want to add Access-Control-Allow-xxx header for Pre-light request from setting origin (http://example.com), have any way to config for it?

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270902/set-apache-headers-conditionally), and [setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) manual, but I can't find any option that I can extract `Origin` info from the request.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: You mean you only want to respond with those headers, if the `Origin` header of the request is `http://example.com`?

Comment: Thanks CBroe for your quickly reply.

> You mean you only want to respond with those headers, if the Origin header of the request is http://example.com?
=> Yes. It's exactly what I want.

I also read above article but it only set condition by request_url. I can't find any option to check Origin header of the request.

Comment: Well that’s the part where you go read up on the `SetEnvIf` directive in the manual then, right? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

Comment: Yep. absolutely I also read it too. 
As manual, the `attribute ` of `SetEnvIf` have `Remote_Host, Remote_Addr, Server_Addr, Request_Method, Request_Protocol, Request_URI`. There is no option that I can extract `Origin` info from request.

Comment: Read it again. `The attribute specified in the first argument can be one of three things:` The first one covers your scenario

Comment: _“An HTTP request header field (see RFC2616 for more information about these); for example: `Host`, `User-Agent`, `Referer`, and `Accept-Language`.”_

Comment: Thanks for remind. With `SetEnvIf Origin http://example.com SIGN` I can control these header was added or didn't. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

As [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) document, `attribute` in `SetEnvIf attribute regex [!]env-variable` syntax, can be `An HTTP request header field (see RFC2616 for more information about these); for example: Host, User-Agent, Referer, and Accept-Language.`

So I can resolve with below config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    SetEnvIf Origin "^http://fiddle.jshell.net$" ORIGIN_COND

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com" env=ORIGIN_COND
    ...   
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks @CRroe and @arco444 make me clearly.